# Show that if $A ⊆ C$ and $B ⊆ D$, then $A × B ⊆ C × D$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Show that if $A ⊆ C$ and $B ⊆ D$, then $A × B ⊆ C × D$

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you tell where you're stuck?

Comment: @Ivan You seem to be new here. People here like it if you tell use the context where you encounter the problem and show us what you already tried.

Comment: (x,y)∈A×B x∈A and y∈B. A⊆C and B⊆D.    x∈C and y∈D (x,y)∈C×D. I UNDERSTAND THE STEPS ABOVE. BUT how (x,y)∈A×B and (x,y)∈C×D show AXB⊆CXD?

Comment: @Ivan Try putting mathematical symbols in dollars: `$y∈D⟺(x,y)∈C×D$` will become $y∈D⟺(x,y)∈C×D$

Comment: we have A⊆C,B⊆D,  (x,y)∈A×B and (x,y)∈C×D now, which means A×B⊆C×D?

Comment: @Ivan This is a definition If $x \in X$ implies $x\in Y$ then $X ⊂ Y$

Comment: We don't have $(x,y) \in A × B$. We have that **if** $(x,y) \in A × B$. **Then** $(x,y) \in C × D$

Comment: if (x,y)∈A×B ,we have (x,y)∈C×D.so because The definition If x∈X implies x∈Y then X⊂Y, we conclude  A×B⊆C×D?

Comment: @Ivan Well done. That is the correct line of reasoning.

Comment: @Ivan you're welcome :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319975/if-a-subseteq-c-and-b-subseteq-d-then-a-times-b-subseteq-c-times-d/531598#531598

I have given a detailed answer to this question here. If you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

We have: $(x,y)\in A\times B\iff x\in A$ and $y\in B$ hence by the hypothesis $x\in C$ and $y\in D\iff (x,y)\in C\times D$

Comment: It is duplicate but this post has different taste. :+)

Answer (score 1):

Ok you know that $A\times B$ just means $A \times B=\{(a,b)|a\in A$ and $b\in B\}$. And we can assume that $A\subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$. Now we want to show $A\times B \subseteq C\times D$. For the proof I would begin by saying "Suppose $A\subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$. 
Let $x\in A\times B$ where $x=(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. We want to show $x\in C\times D$. From here you should be able to complete the proof just from the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Choose some element $(a, b) \in A \times B$.  Since $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$, what can you say about $a$ and $b$?